# Generating Function for a Recurrence: $a_k = 3a_{k−1} + 4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, closed-form

Use generating functions to solve the recurrence relation $a_k = 3a_{k−1} + 4$ with the initial condition $a_0 = 1$.

I have done my work until $(4-x)\sum_\limits0^\infty (n+1)x^n$

and got stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
a_k=3a_{k-1}+4, \quad k=1,2,3,\ldots
$$ setting $ f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$, you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k=3x\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+4\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k
$$
$$
f(x)-a_0=3xf(x)+4\frac{x}{1-x}
$$ giving, with $a_0=1$,

> $$
> f(x)=\frac{3}{1-3x}-\frac{2}{1-x}.\tag1
> $$

Then expand $(1)$ for $|x|<1/3$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh okay from that I converted to the summation and consider to coefficient finally I got 3^n+1 - 2

Thanks a lot !! :D

Comment: @Wongsakorn You are welcome!